# TP-Processorxx in waiting state

Tags: apache, thread-dump

I am using jconsole(along with TDA.jar plugin) to take the thread dump of a remote tomcat 6 server.
I see a lot of TP-Processorxx(90 threads) in waiting state. Find below the thread dump

```
"TP-Processor86" nid=197 state=WAITING
    - waiting on <0x20afbfdd> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    - locked <0x20afbfdd> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:662)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I want to know - what are these TP-Processor threads and what they actually do?
Is there any impact on performace because of these waiting threads?
Are these waiting threads a result of some faulty application code?

Answer (score 0):

If you really interested in understanding/debugging thread dumps, you may want to read the following article :

https://dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-thread-dumps

To answer your question, threads in the waiting state (with the stack trace provided by you) are generally harmless. They are just waiting for the task to arrive in the queue.